# how to inject View model using koin? (for specific use case)

Tags: android, dependency-injection, koin

I am having a shared View Model for activity and it's fragment.

My view model need's argument to be passed when instantiating from the activity(`onCreate` only once)

```
viewModel =ViewModelProviders.of(this,
                                 NoteViewModelFactory(application!!,
                                                      uid = intent!!.getStringExtra("uid")!!))
                             .get(NoteViewModel::class.java)
```

But from fragment i don't need to pass the argument as i am sure the i have the argument's passed once.

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(activity!!).get(NoteViewModel::class.java)
```

In `Koin` i tried doing below.

```
val noteModule = module(override = true) {
    viewModel { (id: String) -> NoteViewModel(androidApplication(), id) }
}
```

in Activity:

```
private val viewModel: NoteViewModel by viewModel { parametersOf(intent!!.getStringExtra("uid")!!) }
```

in Fragment:

```
private val viewModel: NoteViewModel by sharedViewModel()
```

Application Crashed with below error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.andor.navigate.notepad/com.andor.navigate.notepad.listing.NotesActivity}:
>   org.koin.core.error.InstanceCreationException: Could not create
>   instance for
>   [type:Factory,primary_type:'com.andor.navigate.notepad.core.NoteViewModel']
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>        Caused by: org.koin.core.error.InstanceCreationException: Could not create instance for
>   [type:Factory,primary_type:'com.andor.navigate.notepad.core.NoteViewModel']
>           at org.koin.core.instance.DefinitionInstance.create(DefinitionInstance.kt:61)
>           at org.koin.core.instance.FactoryDefinitionInstance.get(FactoryDefinitionInstance.kt:37)
>           at org.koin.core.definition.BeanDefinition.resolveInstance(BeanDefinition.kt:70)
>           at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:165)

I am not able to understand how to solve this using KOIN.

P.S:i am new to koin DI.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything wrong when you init koin in application class? I tried your code without any issuses. I'm using koin version `2.0.1`

```
class App : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        val noteModule = module(override = true) {
            viewModel { (id: String) -> NoteViewModel(androidApplication(), id) }
        }

        startKoin {
            androidContext(this@App)
            modules(
                noteModule
            )
        }
    }

}
```

Activity and fragment:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val viewModel: NoteViewModel by viewModel { parametersOf(intent!!.getStringExtra("uid")) }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        Log.d("NoteViewModel", "id: ${viewModel.id}")

        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_root, Frag()).commit()
    }

}
class Frag : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: NoteViewModel by sharedViewModel()

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        Log.d("NoteViewModel", "id: ${viewModel.id}")
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false)
    }
}
```

View model class:

```
class NoteViewModel (application: Application, val id: String) : AndroidViewModel(application)
```

Comment: Can you please read my question again. I know how to inject viewModel but i have a specific case which i want to solve.

Comment: I have tried above and getting the crash as i have posted in the question

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't pass these type of arguments in `ViewModel` constructor. Instead what you can do is on your Activity's `onCreate()`, you set that passed value to the `ViewModel`. So when you will access that `ViewModel` in your fragment, you'll surely have that value already set.

```
class NoteViewModel (application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application)
{
    var id:String = ""   
}
```

Your koin Module:

```
val noteModule = module(override = true) {
    viewModel { NoteViewModel(androidApplication()) }
}
```

Activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val viewModel: NoteViewModel by viewModel()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        viewModel.id = intent?.getStringExtra("uid")?: ""

        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, MyFrag()).commit()
    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
class MyFrag : Fragment() {

private val viewModel: NoteViewModel by sharedViewModel()

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // your value will be available here.
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false)
}
```

}

Comment: `You shouldn't pass these type of arguments in ViewModel constructor.` but why?

ViewModelFactory is specifically for these kind of cases.

Comment: Well, your code is working for me. I don't know why it doesn't work for you. So, I suggested you one alternative.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62455022/7529648
Also check: https://doc.insert-koin.io/#/koin-android/viewmodel