# Get the same instance of ViewModel in Fragment which is defined in Activity with parameter

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, koin

So, I am using `Koin` for dependency injection, Here is what I did inside a activity

```
class ModuleDetailActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var moduleId:String
    private lateinit var levelModule:Level.Module

    private val moduleViewModel: ModuleViewModel by viewModel { parameterOf(moduleId, levelModule) }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        ...
        ...

        moduleId = intent.getString("module_id")
        levelModule = intent.getParcelable("level_module")

        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Now, I have multiple fragment which `ModuleDetailActivity` can add or replace and I want the same instance of `moduleViewModel` in those fragments without passing any parameters inside `Fragment`.

```
class ModuleDetailFragment : Fragment() {

    private val moduleViewModel: ModuleViewModel by sharedViewModel()

    ...
    ...
}
```

I know this will throw a error and as expected you can see this

```
Caused by: org.koin.core.error.InstanceCreationException: Could not create instance for [Factory:'****.ui.module.ModuleViewModel']
```

This is how I have initialized the module

```
val viewModelModule = module {
    viewModel { (id : String, levelModule:Level.Module) -> ModuleViewModel(id, levelModule, get()) }
}
```

Is there any solution on how I can get the same instance of `ModuleViewModel` defined inside activity without passing parameter inside a `Fragment`?

Answer (score 10):

Using **KOIN**

ViewModel instance can be shared between Fragments and their host Activity.

To inject a shared ViewModel in a Fragment use:

```
by sharedViewModel() - lazy delegate property to inject shared ViewModel instance into a property
getSharedViewModel() - directly get the shared ViewModel instance
```

Just declare the ViewModel only once:

```
val weatherAppModule = module {

   // WeatherViewModel declaration for Weather View components
   viewModel { WeatherViewModel(get(), get()) }

}
```

In your activity:

```
class WeatherActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    /*
     * Declare WeatherViewModel with Koin and allow constructor dependency injection
     */
    private val weatherViewModel by viewModel<WeatherViewModel>()
}
```

In your fragment:

```
class WeatherHeaderFragment : Fragment() {

    /*
     * Declare shared WeatherViewModel with WeatherActivity
     */
    private val weatherViewModel by sharedViewModel<WeatherViewModel>()
}
```

Other fragment:

```
class WeatherListFragment : Fragment() {

    /*
     * Declare shared WeatherViewModel with WeatherActivity
     */
    private val weatherViewModel by sharedViewModel<WeatherViewModel>()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialise `viewModel` as below:

```
class ModuleDetailActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val moduleId: String by lazy {
        intent.getString("module_id")
    }

    private val levelModule: Level.Module by lazy {
        intent.getParcelable("level_module")
    }

    private val moduleViewModel: ModuleViewModel by viewModel {
        parameterOf(moduleId, levelModule)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        ...
        ...

        viewModel.doYourStuff()

        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

We should use `get()` or `inject()` for plain Java objects only. To inject `ViewModel`, they provided separate way as `viewModel()`

Not sure why it isn't working for you.

Comment: I have updated the question and added few detail which I have missed. I understand I can get `ViewModel` instance with `viewModel`. But what I want is the same instance which if defined in activity with parameter in fragment without parameters.

Comment: Brother, I understand how I can define `ViewModel` inside a `Activity`. **Is there a way I can get the same viewmodel inside a fragment without passing the parameters which i have already done in Activity?**

Comment: @Hussain I have used same as you have. Not sure why it isn't working for you. I have shared code from my working example.

Comment: You have mentioned only the activity part. How to do that in fragment? And I don't want to pass the same parameters in fragment.

Comment: @Hussain Fragment portion is correct, same as I have implemented.